# how to browse to a local web site from my ubuntu desktop

Tags: 11.10, networking, webserver

I run a web server just on my local network on a Windows XP machine using IIS.  The main app I created keeps track of all my bookmarks so that no matter which computer I'm using in my home, I have super easy access to all my bookmarks via a well organized web site managed through a database.

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a separate machine that I'm rebuilding.  Currently, I'm able to access files on the web server from ubuntu for file sharing purposes but Firefox redirects me to a random site when I try to access the website like I normally do in Windows.  The url is similar to:

http://mywebserver/myapp/script.pl

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an entry for mywebserver in your `/etc/hosts` file.

e.g. if your Windows Server has IP `a.b.c.d` try appending the following line in your `/etc/hosts` file

```
sudoedit /etc/hosts
```

Then enter the following, replacing `a.b.c.d` with the IP address and `mywebserver` with what you would like to use in the URL field.

```
a.b.c.d     mywebserver
```